# Get a certain amount characters came after a certain word in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Let's say that I have a variable as follows:

```
var MV = "Cat234 Dog347 Fruit228 and I am very strong";
```

I can use the match method to get the numbers out of the string, but not only the numbers after a certain word:

```
var B = MV.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

But how can I get only the numbers that came after Dog, which is 347 (in this example), in a new variable by using replace regex or whatever approach?

Comment: Are you serious? Do not come here, ask for help, and then **complain** when your question does not meet the requirements of the site.  At StackOverflow, you are expected to **show what you have tried**.  Your question has *zero effort* at showing code to solve your own problem.

Comment: I am looking to get some help from coders, and someone thinks that if I use a comma in my edit it gets improved, which part of this is an improvement. This only makes me and other people who are seriously seeking help upset about the result here, I am not here so people decide if my writing is scored 8 for IELTS, I aske a question and it is absolutely clear.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your grammar and everything to do with the fact that you've shown no effort. You've posted no code. What have you actually tried?

Comment: This is a simple question, there is no process actually, I tried using Regex, but I could not figure out how to get the number came after a certain word.

Comment: I suggest you post your attempted regex and your results from what -- what you got versus what you expect. That's quite a bit better than what you've posted so far and would at least demonstrate that you don't expect someone to write your code for you.

Comment: update the question with some of the regexes you've tried so it looks like you've really made some attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See This Example.
https://jsfiddle.net/jsco68qc/

```js
var MV = "Cat234 Dog347 Fruit228 and I am very strong";

var B = MV.toLowerCase().split("dog")[1].match(/\d+/)[0];

document.getElementById("answer").value = B;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="answer"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```js
var MV = "Cat234 Dog347 Fruit228 and I am very strong";

var B = MV.match(/Dog(\d+)/)[1];

console.log(B);
```